# What could be the expression in English, that means "to have different interests, inclinations"

Tags: phrases, expressions

I have this question, because I want to translate one expression from my language, that literally means " we are not belted with the same belt", with the meaning: we are not the same, we are differently inclined. It is not similar to expressions like different strokes for different folks or to each their own, because this is not an axiom. For the context, the sentence goes like this:" but as it turned out we were not all belted with the same belt: when one of us wanted to visit the old cemetery, the other was crawling down to  search for humulus lupulus ( a plant).

So, if anyone has any ideas of any similar expression in english, be welcome to share!

Answer (score 1):

You could say, “we were not of the same mind.”

“of the same mind” means

> having the same thoughts, ideas, opinions, etc. about something
>   She is *of the same mind* as me.

according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of%20the%20same%20mind).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to mean opposites, there are phrases "like oil and water" or "like night and day". That might be too extreme for what you're asking, though.

There's a concept in Christianity that comes from a phrase in the Bible: "unequally yoked". It specifically means a believer being married to a non-believer, but a more casual usage is two people drawn in different directions.

The phrase "cut from the same cloth" means the opposite of what you're asking. English speakers familiar with that phrase would probably understand what you meant if you used "cut from a different cloth" even though I don't think it's widely recognized as a standard idiom.

Comment: I was typing a comment suggesting that the OP use "...not all cut from the same cloth" when your answer notification popped up. It's not spot on but translating idioms from one language to another is rarely an exact science.

Comment: I think "cut from the same cloth" IS widely recognized. It was the first thing that popped into my mind when I saw this question as well. It seems to be an accurate translation of what the OP is trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that you were not [***on the same page***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20the%20same%20page). This is a fairly common idiom in the US; from Merriam-Webster:

> agreeing about something (such as how things should be done) · Try to get employees and clients *on the same page*.

It's apparently a relatively recent phrase, perhaps originating from business discussions when folks are looking at complicated, many-page documents. See, for example, the EL&U question *[What's the origin of the idiom “on the same page”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117519/whats-the-origin-of-the-idiom-on-the-same-page)* and its accepted answer. In the negative, it's regularly used in situations such as your example, when different folks have different agendas.